# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not working after setting initial ViewController manually

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

After i set my initial ViewController manually in the `AppDelegate.swift` 
my UISwipeGestureRecognizer is not working.

This is how my AppDelegate look like:

```
        self.mainNavigationController = UINavigationController()
        var mainController: UIViewController? = TineLineViewController()
        self.mainNavigationController!.pushViewController(mainController!, animated: true)
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window!.rootViewController = mainController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and this is how my UISwipeGestureRecognizer is set in the initial ViewController:

```
        let postLeft : Selector = "postLeft:"
        let postLeftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: postLeft)
        postLeftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        goToPostButton.addGestureRecognizer(postLeftSwipe)
```

And this is my `postLeft` method which instantiate a new ViewController and navigate to it.

```
func postLeft(sender: AnyObject) {

        println("left swipe to push...")
        let secondViewController = PostCreateController()
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

When I swipe, the `postLeft` method was called, I can see the println left swipe to push, but the application doesn't changed the view.

Does anybody have any solution to solve this issue?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

i change my postLeft method. and by the console i see my new viewController class instantiates but it's not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't set your navigationController correctly,

try this instead of `self.navigationController!.pushViewController`

```
 let secondViewController = PostCreateController()
 self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: it's throw this:  Warning: Attempt to present "<KallerRadar.PostCreateController: 0x7fb43050d7c0> on <KallerRadar.TineLineViewController: 0x7fb430678560> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" and the new View is not showing up :(

Comment: check that you are not pointing that view with performSegueWithIdentifer:sender also

Comment: i don't have any performSegueWithIdentifer method.. i don't have story board neihter..

Comment: is your PostCreateController view class cocoa class?

Comment: Yes, it is. and by the console messages i think the class instantiate when but it's not showing up.. :( so the view doesn't change..

Comment: how can i remove it? that instance does not exist in my initial view controller.. :(

Comment: remove that lines self.mainNavigationController = UINavigationController() ; self.mainNavigationController!.pushViewController(mainController!, animated: true) in app delegate

Comment: if i remoce this line my application can't start with this error message : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)